# explanation schematics stm32

Tags: stm32, schematics, bluetooth-low-energy

Can somebody explain to me the followings symbols in this schematic?

1. "≫" . See pins 2(BLE_TEST8), 3 (BLE_TEST9), 4/7 (BLE_INT)
2. "⌒NC". See pins connected to USART2_TX/RX
3. "⌒0R". See pin 11 (BLE_SPI_CS)

[image]

Comment: We can't explain you. We could, potentially, explain something _to_ you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ">>" and "<<"

They are off-page connectors. Somewhere in the schematic, the same label can be found again. That is where this is connected.
Used for connecting parts to different pages in the same schematic (sometimes even om the same page for less tangled lines in the schematic, personally I don't like that).

2. "⌒NC"

Jumper, Not Connected. I.e. a jumper which can be shorted to make contact through it, but by default not connected.

3. "⌒0R"

Jumper as above, but this one is shorted with 0 Ω.

Comment: Are you sure NC isn't "normally closed"? Because that's how I would interpret that--the exact opposite of "not connected".

Comment: @Hearth When it comes to component values on a schematic, NC is somewhat common for "No Connect" or "Not Connected" or possibly "No Component", all with the same meaning. Also when combined with the fact that this schematic also contains 0R jumpers, one can be pretty sure the designer meant no connection.

Comment: @Hearth NC on the schematic means "not connected"

Answer (score 1):

- << "this is a signal coming in from a different schematic sheet". Use your PDF viewer's search function to find "USART2_RX" on other pages
- ⌒0R "This is a jumper, it is closed by a 0Ω resistor"
- ⌒NC *this is pretty non-standard, and I do not applaud the designer for this choice of symbols; there's "open jumper" symbols that would have been perfectly clear, or the "DNP", do not populate, annotation that this isn't populated by default*
   "This is a jumper, which is not connected by default" (i.e. two unconnected contacts next to each other; to connect them, solder in a 0Ω resistor or just bridge the two contacts with a blob of solder)

Answer (score 0):

1. is just a symbol used by the CAD software to indicate an off-page connector. It could be different for different software. The CAD software could have two different symbols for off-page connectors; input and output, but they both do the same thing and only look different for user readability because the software does not know or care. It just knows two points are connected together. Some CAD software won't even have a symbol at all and just have a net name.
2. and 3 are jumpers